# ¿Como Cargar un SfComboBox cuando se selecciona un valor en otro SfComboBox?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

Buenas amigo estoy tratando de Cargar unos datos con valores que me devuelve una API en un SfComboBox (que es componente de SyncFusion para Blazor ) cuando se selecciona o se cambia de valor en otro SfComboBox he tratado con diferentes formas pero no se recarga con los nuevos datos más o menos como el AutoPostback en un Dropdown de VB.Net